# How to format a Time as "2015-10-09T23:51:13.449Z" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Time.now.utc.iso8601
=> "2015-10-09T23:51:13Z"
```

This format is close to the desired format `2015-10-09T23:51:13.449Z` except it does not show the decimal of the seconds.

FWIW, this is the format that comes out of Mongoid. I think it is the same as Rails AR format.

Rails 4.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the extra precision, do it yourself with [`strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-strftime):

```
Time.now.utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ')
```

The `%L` is the extra bit you're looking for:

> `%L` - Millisecond of the second (000..999)
>   The digits under millisecond are truncated to not produce 1000.

Comment: I wonder if there is a ActiveRecord method for this..And does Rails define it using `.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ')`?

Comment: ActiveRecord and Mongoid are entirely different things. If you're using Mongoid then you should be getting an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instance for you timestamp fields and that supports `strftime` like everything else. Anyway, if you need a specific format, do it yourself with `strftime`, everything sensible will end up calling `strftime` to do the formatting anyway.